# Xcopy command throws 'Invalid number of parameters' when run as predeploy of Firebase functions, but works fine when run directly from terminal

Tags: windows, firebase, batch-file, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I am trying to host a nuxtjs app on Firebase using cloud functions following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aTvdnqY3ek) (around 12:30).

One of the required steps is copying a folder with batch commands in a `predeploy` hook of `firebase deploy --only functions`. The tutorial uses Linux (?) commands and I'm trying to replicate it on Windows.

I was able to create a command that works correctly (!) if I run it directly from terminal:

```
xcopy .\.nuxt\*.* '.\functions\nuxt\' /e /i /y /q
```

It also works if I put it to `package.json` as a test script and run it with `npm run test` (obviously additional `\` characters are needed in `package.json`):

```
"scripts": {  
    "test": "xcopy .\\.nuxt\\*.* '.\\functions\\nuxt\\' /e /i /y /q"
}
```

But when I put the very string from above into `firebase.json` like this:

```
"functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "xcopy .\\.nuxt\\*.* '.\\functions\\nuxt\\' /e /i /y /q"
    ]
  },
```

and then run command `firebase deploy --only functions`, the CLI displays message:

`Running command: xcopy .\.nuxt\*.* '.\functions\nuxt\' /e /i /y /q`
and an error: `Invalid number of parameters`. The displayed command is identical to the command I successfully run manually in the terminal. I can copy it from that message paste into terminal and it will work. Yet when triggered by the firebase deploy mechanism it throws an error.

Usual answer for 'Invalid number of parameters' error is lack of quotation marks around the path. I have tried various combinations of `''` or `\" \"`, but neither works, although they fail in various ways (`cannot find file: *.*'` or `Analysis error`).

What can be the cause of this and how to solve it? What is the right way to write this command?

Comment: Technically I would have expected `"xcopy .\\.nuxt\\*.* '.\\functions\\nuxt\\' /e /i /y /q"` to be `"xcopy.exe \".nuxt\\*.*\" \"functions\\nuxt\\\" /EIQY"`. Windows uses doublequotes to surround filenames/strings, singlequotes are just trated as any other character. I have used ```\\\``` because the trailing backwards slash on the end of the directory name means that the directory will be created if it does not exist, so the first one escapes the second, and the third one escapes the nested doublequote.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Your suggestion throws `Analysis error` as it is. It works, but only if I remove the parameters `/EIQY`, which I'd rather prefer to avoid (adding `/e /i /y /q` doesn't work either). Would you have a suggestion how to fix this new problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround - I 'outsourced' all file operations into a batch file and referred to that file in the `firebase.json` `predeploy` hook:

```
"functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm run build && predeploy.bat"
    ]
  }
```

Contents of `predeploy.bat`:

```
if exist functions\nuxt rmdir /S /Q functions\nuxt\
xcopy.exe .nuxt functions\nuxt /e /i /y /q /s
xcopy.exe nuxt.config.js functions\ /i /q /y
```

I had a problem also with `rmdir` not functioning properly if run from the Firebase's `predeploy` hook, but it works seamlessly if it is called from batch file that is called from `predeploy` hook (?!).